# Changing tumblr theme according to posts

Tags: css, themes, tumblr

I'm searching for a way to completely change the css style of a tumblr blog according to the posts. I already find that we could do that element by element, but what I want is a bit different.

To be more specific :
I have 2 different themes : a dark one and a light one. 
On the same blog, I would like to use the dark one for the posts which I consider as category1 and the light one for the posts I consider as category2. 
Moreover, I would like to be able to show posts of both categories, using the light theme.

Is there anyway to achieve this easily ?

**EDIT**

What I call a category is like the subject of the post, so I'll probably have to use tags to differentiate the posts.

Comment: what do you mean by "category"? image vs text vs video...? background color of the image? has a certain tag? in any case, if you can get the category using javascript, you can apply the css dynamically

Comment: I have edited my post to be clearer about what I call category.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify: `.light` is category1, `.dark` is category2. The CSS would look something like:

```
body.light {
    background: white;
    ...
}
body.dark {
    background: black;
    ...
}
```

The template logic would look something like:

```
{block:IndexPage}
<body class="light">
{block:Posts}
<!-- Add Post Logic Here -->
{/block:Posts}
</body>
{/block:IndexPage}

{block:PermalinkPage}
{block:Posts}
<body class="{TagsAsClasses}">
<!-- Add Post Logic Here -->
</body>
{/block:Posts}
{/block:PermalinkPage}

{block:TagPage}
<body class="{Tag}">
{block:Posts}
<!-- Add Post Logic Here -->
{/block:Posts}
</body>
{/block:TagPage}
```

Set `.light` on the Indexpage as this should always be light.

On the Permalink page use `{TagsAsClasses}` to output all tags for a post, including either `.light` or `.dark`.

On the Tagged page use `{Tag}` to return either `.light` or `.dark`.

Hope that helps.